# Create pandas df from JSON where Column Headers and Rows are in separate arrays

Tags: python, pandas

An API is sending me data in the form of:

```
{
    uselessInfo: blabla,
    headers: [
        {type:DIMENSION, name:DATE},
        {type:DIMENSION, name:COUNTRY},
        {type:METRIC, name:REVENUE}
    ],
    rows: [
        ["2014-09-29","Germany",435],
        ["2014-09-28","USA",657],
        ...
        ["2014-09-13","Spain",321]
    ],
    average: [ some unwanted info ],
    total: [ some unwanted info ]
}
```

I want to create a dataframe in pandas from this object, using only:

- the headers info to name my columns
- the rows for the data
- And ignore the rest.

So far, I have tried to change parameters in pandas' ".read_json" but without any good results. I could not find any similar examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas.read_json` can not turn *all* JSONs into DataFrames. The JSON has to have one of the formats [described in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.read_json.html#pandas-io-json-read-json) under the `orient` parameter.

Instead, use `json.loads` to convert the data into a Python object, then pick out the header and rows to form the DataFrame:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

content = '''{
    "uselessInfo": "blabla", 
    "headers": [
        { "type": "DIMENSION", "name": "DATE" }, 
        { "type": "DIMENSION", "name": "COUNTRY" }, 
        { "type": "METRIC", "name": "REVENUE" }
    ],
    "rows": [ [ "2014-09-29", "Germany", 435 ], 
        [ "2014-09-28", "USA", 657 ], 
        [ "2014-09-13", "Spain", 321 ]
    ], 
    "average": [ "some unwanted info" ], 
    "total": [ "some unwanted info" ]
}'''
data = json.loads(content)


columns = [dct['name'] for dct in data['headers']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data['rows'], columns=columns)
print(df)
```

yields

```
         DATE  COUNTRY  REVENUE
0  2014-09-29  Germany      435
1  2014-09-28      USA      657
2  2014-09-13    Spain      321
```

Comment: Wow, sounds like a very straightforward workaround but could not think of it by myself :) Thanks a lot!