# How to read this JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to read such a JSON file in Python, to save only two of the values of each response part:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "time":2,
   "params":{
     "q":"query",
     "rows":"2",
     "wt":"json"}},
 "response":{"results":2,"start":0,"docs":[
     {
       "name":["Peter"],
       "country":["England"],
       "age":["23"]},
     {
       "name":["Harry"],
       "country":["Wales"],
       "age":["30"]}]
 }}
```

For example, I want to put the name and the age in a table. I already tried it this way (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120553/create-pandas-df-from-json-where-column-headers-and-rows-are-in-separate-arrays) topic), but it's not working for me.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file = open("myfile.json")

data = json.loads(file)

columns = [dct['name', 'age'] for dct in data['response']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data['response'], columns=columns)
print(df)
```

I also have seen more solutions of reading a JSON file, but that all were solutions of a JSON file with no other header values at the top, like responseHeader in this case. I don't know how to handle that. Anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
with open("myfile.json") as f:
    columns = [(dic["name"],dic["age"]) for dic in json.load(f)["response"]["docs"]]
    print(columns)
```

result:

```
[(['Peter'], ['23']), (['Harry'], ['30'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the list data["response"]["docs"] to pandas directly as it's a recordset.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data["response"]["docs"])`
print(df)

>>>      name    country   age
    0  [Peter]  [England]  [23]
    1  [Harry]    [Wales]  [30]
```

The data in you DatFrame will be bracketed though as you can see. If you want to remove the brackets you can consider the following:

```py
for column in df.columns:
    df.loc[:, column] = df.loc[:, column].str.get(0)
    if column == 'age':
        df.loc[:, column] = df.loc[:, column].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = {"responseHeader":{
   "status":0,
   "time":2,
   "params":{
     "q":"query",
     "rows":"2",
     "wt":"json"}},
 "response":{"results":2,"start":0,"docs":[
     {
       "name":["Peter"],
       "country":["England"],
       "age":["23"]},
     {
       "name":["Harry"],
       "country":["Wales"],
       "age":["30"]}]
 }}
data = [(x['name'][0], x['age'][0]) for x in 
        sample['response']['docs']]
df = pd.DataFrame(names, columns=['name', 
        'age'])
```